# How to use nginx as a proxy (not reverse proxy)?

Tags: proxy, nginx, http-proxy

Seems most people are using nginx as a reverse proxy. It possible to use it as a proxy? So people in the network will go through nginx in order to access the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The usual term to distinguish this mode is "**forward** proxy".

According to various sources, Nginx is *not* designed to act as a forward proxy.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060028/how-to-use-nginx-as-forward-proxy-for-any-requested-location
- lots of googling

Still, it *could* do so for cleartext HTTP queries, as fundamentally both modes use a similar mechanism, the biggest difference is whether the destination host is set in config (for reverse proxies) or taken from the client request (forward proxies):

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

(However, this is just relaying, not caching like with Squid.)

More importantly, Nginx doesn't support the HTTP `CONNECT` command necessary for transparent HTTPS relaying (i.e. non-MITM). This can be provided through external modules:

- https://github.com/reiz/nginx_proxy

Answer (score 0):

yes.  There is a module/patch to get forward proxy functionality https://github.com/chobits/ngx_http_proxy_connect_module

https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-use-nginx-as-an-https-forward-proxy-server_595799

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).